# Same unique repository class for Room and Datastore, or two distinct repositories

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack-datastore

I'm trying to include a Datastore with Datastore preferences into a project with Android and Room. I'm trying to follow the clean architecture guide that defines a Repository class as a mediator between the data layer and the UI layer, like this:

[image: Repository pattern]

Then, my repository class now only contains references to the Room database.

When adding my DataStore preferences, i should reference it into this unique repository class, o it must be referenced into a new repository class?

Comment: This is pretty opinionated. You can have a single repository for ease and not having to manage 2 separate classes. Or you can have multiple repository class to separate concerns. Eventually if you use 2 of these, you'll have to use 2 variables everywhere you want to use them.